# HP CM1415 scan to cloud or scan to email/FTP?

Tags: email, cloud, scanning, hp-laserjet

I'd like to have possibility to scan using HP CM1415fnw multifunction printer and send it automatically to cloud (e.g. Dropbox), email or FTP server.

I've installed [new firmware](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&tmp_geoLoc=true&softwareitem=kj-85662-10), which is described to have a feature "scan document and upload the result to Cloud if printer has network connection.", but I can't find it.

I know that newer HP MFPs have such functionality. [Here's a video about pretty advanced app.](http://vimeo.com/43617945)

Does anyone know how to run it? Is it country restricted (I've noticed that I can't use a lot HP Web Apps for my printer because I'm not in America).

Comment: https://h30495.www3.hp.com/help#eprint

Comment: Link above does not contain any answer.